# How do I invoke a process with a certain java binary, and all processes called by that process?

Tags: linux, command-line, java

I need to be able to call a certain process with a certain java binary. Call that process "foo". However, foo also invokes several other processes via java, but foo is a black box to me. When foo invokes those processes, it just runs "java bar", "java bat", etc. How do I tell foo and any processes called by foo, to use /full/path/to/java only? Essentially I want to use "update-alternatives" for a single shell session and/or single process tree.

OS is Centos7, shell is bash.

**Setting the system java is out of the question, as other processes on the system need a different java binary.**

Comment: One method might be `PATH=/custom/java/bin:$PATH foo` assuming everything else in that directory is okay to list first in `PATH` and that `foo` or downstream of that do not fiddle with `PATH` on their own...

Answer (score 1):

Create a directory `~/myjava` that contains only a symbolic link to `/full/path/to/bin/java`.

```
mkdir ~/myjava
ln -s /full/path/to/bin/java ~/myjava/java
```

Run the process with this directory at the start of the command search path.
In addition, some programs look at the environment variable `JAVA_HOME`. Make sure that it's consistent. The actual `java` executable should be in a subdirectory called `bin` or `$JAVA_HOME`.

```
PATH=~/myjava:$PATH JAVA_HOME=/full/path/to foo
```